# PHPCI showing fatal error Class 'PHPCI\\Controller' not found in C:\phpci\vendor\block8\b8framework\b8\Application.php

Tags: php

As in the topic when entering public directory of PHPCI installation (C:\phpci\public) with virtual host set up I get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'PHPCI\Controller' not found in C:\phpci\vendor\block8\b8framework\b8\Application.php on line 93

I suppose it is running index.php file in the public folder which looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
* PHPCI - Continuous Integration for PHP
*
* @copyright    Copyright 2014, Block 8 Limited.
* @license      https://github.com/Block8/PHPCI/blob/master/LICENSE.md
* @link         https://www.phptesting.org/
*/

session_set_cookie_params(43200); // Set session cookie to last 12 hours.
session_start();

require_once('../bootstrap.php');

$fc = new PHPCI\Application($config, new b8\Http\Request());
print $fc->handleRequest();
```

The function leading to the problem is in Application.php:

```
protected function loadController($class)
{
    $controller = new $class($this->config, $this->request, $this->response);
    $controller->init();

    return $controller;
}
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Well, how do you expect us to give a solution if you do not post the code leading to that error message? The error message itself is pretty clear: the class is unknown. So question is why do you claim it should be known? Where should it come from? If you can answer that, then you will find the answer to your question :-)

Comment: Ok I think it is PHPCI tool specific and I think it runs index.php in the folder public.

Comment: That certainly is _not_ the code leading to the error. The error message clearly names the file and line number. Why don't you simply look at that error message and start digging where it points to?

Comment: Anyway, without precise info we cannot help here. So just a general hint: most likely that framework uses "autoloading" which relies on a Number of things. Those "things" can be configured probably. So maybe it is worth looking into your configuration, so the configuration of php and especially that framework you use.

Comment: I pasted the function leading to error. Do you want me to paste whole file?

Comment: OK, you did provide the line in question now. So the class name is actually dynamic in there. What does `$class` contain? I can only assume "Controller" which sounds broken to me. Typically it would be something like "somethingController", might be "indexController" here. Next you could check what controller classes exist. And where that function is called from.

Comment: I think I should ask somebody developing this framework but they don't have access to forum. Maybe I will try to contact Block 8 company developing it.